# How to use IDispatchMessageInspector in a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

I am trying to use [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) in a WCF service implementation to access custom header values.

Something like:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<string> GetNames()
    {
        var headerInspector = new CustomHeaderInspector();

        // Where do request & client channel come from?
        var values = headerInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref request, clientChannel, OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext);            
    }
}
```

I've implemented my own IDispatchMessageInspector class.

```
public class CustomHeaderInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        var userName = prop.Headers["Username"];

        return userName;
    }
}
```

How do I pass

- System.ServiceModel.Channels.**Message** and
- System.ServiceModel.**IClientChannel**

to **AfterReceiveRequest** called *from the service implementation?*

**EDIT:**

Many articles like [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20130806230959/http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx) or [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/29/creating-a-wcf-idispatchmessageinspector.aspx), give examples on how to implement your own `ServiceBehavior`. So your service implementation looks like this:

```
[MyCustomBehavior]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<string> GetNames()
    {
        // Can you use 'MyCustomBehavior' here to access the header properties?
    }
}
```

So with this, can I access `MyCustomBehavior` somehow within the service operation method to access custom header values?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/29/creating-a-wcf-idispatchmessageinspector.aspx this might be very helpful

Answer (score 7):

You have to configure the

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add 
      name="serviceInterceptors" 
      type="CustomHeaderInspector , MyDLL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Then the extension will be handled in your WCF stack. The service itself has no notion of the `serviceInterceptors` and you do not have to do something like in your first code block. The WCF stack will inject you Inspector.

[MSDN: system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Do you have any insight on where to Implement the IDispatchmessageInspector? I started another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171943/how-and-where-to-implement-the-idispatchmessageinspector

Answer (score 5):

I'm using IClientMessageInspector for same goal.
Here is how you can apply them from code:

```
 var serviceClient = new ServiceClientClass(binding, endpointAddress);
serviceClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(
            new MessageInspectorEndpointBehavior<YourMessageInspectorType>());


/// <summary>
/// Represents a run-time behavior extension for a client endpoint.
/// </summary>
public class MessageInspectorEndpointBehavior<T> : IEndpointBehavior
    where T: IClientMessageInspector, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements a modification or extension of the client across an endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The endpoint that is to be customized.</param>
    /// <param name="clientRuntime">The client runtime to be customized.</param>
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new T());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement to pass data at runtime to bindings to support custom behavior.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The endpoint to modify.</param>
    /// <param name="bindingParameters">The objects that binding elements require to support the behavior.</param>
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements a modification or extension of the service across an endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The endpoint that exposes the contract.</param>
    /// <param name="endpointDispatcher">The endpoint dispatcher to be modified or extended.</param>
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement to confirm that the endpoint meets some intended criteria.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The endpoint to validate.</param>
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }
}
```

And here is sample implementation of MessageInspector I'm using to pass client version to server, and retrieve server version in custom headers:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a message inspector object that can be added to the <c>MessageInspectors</c> collection to view or modify messages.
/// </summary>
public class VersionCheckMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables inspection or modification of a message before a request message is sent to a service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The message to be sent to the service.</param>
    /// <param name="channel">The WCF client object channel.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The object that is returned as the <paramref name="correlationState " /> argument of
    /// the <see cref="M:System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message@,System.Object)" /> method.
    /// This is null if no correlation state is used.The best practice is to make this a <see cref="T:System.Guid" /> to ensure that no two
    /// <paramref name="correlationState" /> objects are the same.
    /// </returns>
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(new VersionMessageHeader());
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables inspection or modification of a message after a reply message is received but prior to passing it back to the client application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reply">The message to be transformed into types and handed back to the client application.</param>
    /// <param name="correlationState">Correlation state data.</param>
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var serverVersion = string.Empty;
        var idx = reply.Headers.FindHeader(VersionMessageHeader.HeaderName, VersionMessageHeader.HeaderNamespace);
        if (idx >= 0)
        {
            var versionReader = reply.Headers.GetReaderAtHeader(idx);
            while (versionReader.Name != "ServerVersion"
                   && versionReader.Read())
            {
                serverVersion = versionReader.ReadInnerXml();
                break;
            }
        }

        ValidateServerVersion(serverVersion);
    }

    private static void ValidateServerVersion(string serverVersion)
    {
        // TODO...
    }
}

public class VersionMessageHeader : MessageHeader
{
    public const string HeaderName = "VersionSoapHeader";
    public const string HeaderNamespace = "<your namespace>";
    private const string VersionElementName = "ClientVersion";

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return HeaderName; }
    }

    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return HeaderNamespace; }
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(
            VersionElementName,
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to implement custom *IDispatchMessageInspector* to retrieve custom headers, it can be done from service operation method like this:

```
var mp = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
var property = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)mp[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
var userName = property.Headers["Username"];
```

It makes sense to implement custom dispatch message inspector if you want to abort message processing, for example if credentials are missing - you can just throw FaultException in this case.

But if you still want to pass value from dispatch message inspector to service operation method - probably it can be passed through some singleton along with call identifier (session id), to be extracted later by method, or using [wcf extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733816%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What I did to access the details I set the following inside `IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest`

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "Membership Provider"), roles);`

I've omitted the authentication code from this.

To access the value from the service method, you can call

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 0):

On the MSDN page that you linked to there is also a description how an inspector can be inserted and also an example of that. To quote:

> Typically, message inspectors are inserted by a service behavior, an endpoint behavior, or a contract behavior. The behavior then adds the message inspector to the DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors collection.

Later on you have the following examples:

- Implementing custom IDispatchMessageInspector
- Implementing custom IServiceBehavior that adds the inspector to the runtime.
- Configuration of the behavior via .config file.

That should be enough to get you started. Otherwise feel free to ask :)

If you just want to get access to headers from within your service, you could try `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders`.