# How and where to implement the IDispatchMessageInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

Based on the SO question: [How to use IDispatchMessageInspector in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213782/how-to-use-idispatchmessageinspector-in-a-wcf-service)

I am still confused on where to implement the methods that execute code to "do something" with the inspected message.

From reading [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) it appears that I need to have a class that implements `IDispatchMessageInspector` which has these two methods `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply`.

However, I am not understanding where to or how to use those methods.

For example if I wanted to modify an element in the inbound request message before it was dispatched to its operation.

Is this done in the class I create for the servicebehavior which implements my `ServiceContract` Interface?

Comment: [MSDN has a detailed example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @nodots, thanks for the link, it was a bit more detailed than what I was looking at. I downloaded the WCF sample projects and was able to step through their code to see what I need to do.