# Handling custom soap header in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, soapheader

I am creating WCF Service to receive a message (strings). It has soap request has header as shown below. I went thru so many example that I found on internet, but I could not understand any of those thoroughly.

I found this article is very helpful but still could not make it works
**`http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors`**

After reading several article, I come to know that I need to handle the following area (a)SOAP Header (b) Message Inspector (c) Client Context and (d) Server Context class

1. How do I handle mustUnderstand header
2. I need to capture value passed `messageid`, `ReplyTo`, `To`, `From`, `Action`

*The following soap message need to be consumed*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b</a:Action>
    <a:From><a:Address>urn:oid:1.2.3.4.5.6.1234567.10.70.142.2</a:Address>
    </a:From>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:3a40ebfe-2abc-4de9-b6f6-06c7962f6050</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
    <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To>https://localhost/MyWCFService/Service.asmx</a:To>
</soapenv:Header>
```

...

Comment: If you're able to intercept the message as a `Message` object, you can read the `Header` property. Use a `IDispatchMessageInspector` in that case.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh sample code would be helpful

Comment: Hi Shai. why you required the custom behavior. Do you want any logging or auditing in your application for each request?

Comment: I need to be able to capture messageId, I need to able to handle mustunderstand. I am still having trouble understanding how I am supposed to accomplish it. Please advise.

Comment: implement a message inspector using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx . Then you'll need to inspect the `Message.Header` to access what's sent to the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a WCF Service and you try inspect the SOAP message, you can  implement the [IDispatchMessageInspector Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) Also, for WCF client refer to [IClientMessageInspector Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx)

These are some usefull links:

http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com.tr/2011/03/implementing-idispatchmessageinspector.html

[How to use IDispatchMessageInspector in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213782/how-to-use-idispatchmessageinspector-in-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0):

To read the value of a custom soap header in my WCF service I was able to use the following in the service callback:

```
int nSubscriptionIdHeader = Headers.FindHeader("SubscriptionId", CommonNamespaces.LumosManager);
string strSubscriptionId = Headers.GetHeader<string>(nSubscriptionIdHeader);
```