# IDispatchMessageInspector not working WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

I have working WCF service where I need to add some functionality regarding authorization. I have have created class which inherits from `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and successfully added it in `app.config`. It's working properly.

I also need to implement class which implements `IDispatchMessageInspector`, so I could do some message validation.

I have followed many examples like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/), [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector), [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37156/Focus-on-the-Extension-of-WCF-Behavior), [this](https://www.rhyous.com/2015/04/14/basic-token-service-for-wcf-services-part-3-token-validation-in-idispatchmessageinspector/), [this](https://ovaismehboob.com/2011/06/23/inspecting-messages-in-wcf/) and some others. Also questions in SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213782/how-to-use-idispatchmessageinspector-in-a-wcf-service).

They all seem to have same configuration in `app.config` file. However, when I try that and run code, it seems that class implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector` is never being called when I debug. I've added break points, but they are never being hit.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension" type="MultipleEndpoints.MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension, RL_Managed_Service" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RLServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyProject.Services.AuthorizationService,MyProject"/>
      <MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RLServiceBehavior" name="MultipleEndpoints.RL_Managed_Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MultipleEndpoints.container_db_ops" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--  --><add baseAddress="http://localhost:49224/My_Service/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fixed the config I think I know the reason. You try to register your behavior extension as service behavior, while `IDispatchMessageInspector` should be registered at endpoint level (like in the [link you mentioned](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/) - see the last example there).
Here is config file that should work for you:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension" type="MultipleEndpoints.MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension, RL_Managed_Service" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RLServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyProject.Services.AuthorizationService,MyProject"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RLEndpointBehavior">
      <MessageInspectorBehaviourExtension />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RLServiceBehavior" name="MultipleEndpoints.RL_Managed_Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="RLEndpointBehavior" contract="MultipleEndpoints.container_db_ops" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--  --><add baseAddress="http://localhost:49224/My_Service/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: There was mistake only in this post. Actual code has proper names :(

Comment: Updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I was like 100% sure that I haven't mixed `serviceBehaviors` with `endpointBehaviors`. Probably this was my issue. Thanks very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way I could register `IDispatchMessageInspector` without `app.config`. In `OnStart' method you can simply loop through endpoints.

```
service = New ServiceHost(GetType(My_Service))

For Each endpoint In service.Description.Endpoints
    If Not endpoint.Contract.Name.Equals("IMetadataExchange") Then
        endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(New MessageInspectorBehaviour)
    End If
Next
```